# Unity- Vs code can't find my project . Error Message: Couldn't find a project to run

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-code

I downloaded Unity 2021.3.5f1 and Vs Code. I tried to open a C# script via Vs Code.

I chose Vs Code as an External Script Editor. I downloaded C# extension and .Net Sdk. I already ensured project ( C# script) is in `C:\Users\UMUT\Desktop\Unity Projects\My project\Assets\Scripts`.

How can I solve this error?

Project in this warning means C# script right?

Full Error Message:

> Couldn't find a project to run. Ensure a project exists in
> C:\Users\Umut\Desktop\Unity Projects\My project\Assets\Scripts, or
> pass the path to the project using --project.

Comment: When does this happen? When you try to debug? A word of warning anyway, Unity's support of VS Code has been abandoned. It might be wise to switch to Visual Studio Community Edition instead.

Comment: Did you install the Visual Studio Code package in the Unity editor Package Manager? https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/other/unity

Comment: @Bart it happens when I try to debug.

Comment: @RetiredNinja I already installed that package.